# Add legend to indicate shapes

Tags: r, ggplot2

Need some help with adding legend for shapes used in the plot as described below. The plot is as below -  its a box plot, points for means, error bars for confidence interval.

The resulting plot is as below - **how do I add a legend to this so as to tell that the `red circles` indicate the `mean` and the `green error bars` indicate `confidence interval`  ?** - like in the image below

**Required legend**

[image: Legend]

**Plot**
[image: Box plot with mean & ci]

The data and code used to generate the above is given below for reference.

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(mtcars[,1], mtcars[,2])) #mtcars[, 1:2]
colnames(df) <- c("metric", "group")
df$group <- factor(df$group)

p1 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=group, y=metric ) ) +
  geom_boxplot()

metric_means <- aggregate(df$metric, list(df$group), mean) 
metric_ci_95 <- aggregate(df$metric, list(df$group), function(x){1.96*sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))})
metric_mean_ci = data.frame(group=metric_means[,1],mean=metric_means[,2], ci=metric_ci_95[,2])

# plot mean
p1 <- p1 + geom_point(data=metric_means, aes(x=metric_means[,1], y=metric_means[,2]),
                      colour="red", shape=21, size=2)

#plot confidence interval
p1 <- p1 + geom_errorbar(data=metric_mean_ci, aes(ymin=mean-ci, ymax=mean+ci, x=group, y=mean),
                         color="green", width=.1)

p1
```

What needs to be added to the above code so as to get the legend that reveal the stat summary that the circle and error bar shapes indicate?

Comment: What happens if you add `show.legend = TRUE` as arguments within the `geom_point()` and the `geom_errorbar()` functions?

Comment: @Phil - do not see any legend with the thing you've proposed.

Comment: To get a legend in ggplot, you need to map a value/variable to an aesthetic in `aes`. Moving the `color` or `shape` parameters inside `aes` will get you something, but likely not what you want, which may take more rearranging.

Comment: @user3206440 "legend can be a guide for fill, colour, linetype, shape, or other aesthetics". So if you want a legend, you will have to include that variable in aesthetics.

Comment: Seems unlikely that you created that location of a mean properly.

Comment: @42- can you elaborate on the comment - how would rather you create the `location of a mean` properly ?

Comment: I was just looking at the plot. The mean should be closer to the "box". I cannot test the code because the data is not provided.

Comment: @42- the data is not normally distributed - it is biased towards higher edge with lot of heavy outliers - but you wont see those outliers in the chart as they have been removed via `outlier.shape = NA`. But the question is general in nature.

Comment: Can you add a small example of "metric_means" and "metric_means_ci" to your question?  The earlier advice of moving `color` inside `aes` plus `scale_color_manual` and `override.aes` should get you at least close to what you want.

Comment: @aosmith - updated the question to use the standard `mtcars` dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to color them separately, you can use this code. I am using `geom_linerange` instead of `geom_errorbar` to get a vertical line in the legend. In addition, as suggested, I am mapping colors inside of `aes` to get the legend, and then I am using `override.aes` to limit what plots for each of the values.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=group, y=metric ) ) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(data=metric_means
             , aes(x=metric_means[,1]
                   , y=metric_means[,2]
                   , colour = "Mean")
             , shape=21, size=2) +
  geom_linerange(data=metric_mean_ci
                 , aes(ymin=mean-ci
                      , ymax=mean+ci
                      , x=group
                      , y=mean
                      , color="95% CI")
                ) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("green", "red")) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c("solid", "blank")
                                                   , shape = c(NA, 1))))
```

Gives:

[image]

An alternative, which would require less complicated set up, is to use some of the functions already available to you, specifically, `stat_summary`:

```
ggplot(data=df
       , aes(x=group, y=metric ) ) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(
    aes(color = "Mean and 95% CI")
    , fun.data = mean_cl_normal
    )
```

Gives:

[image]

Comment: This is pretty good. One question, why is that you used `geom_linerange` instead of `geom_errorbar` - is it not possible to get that `errorbar` in legend ?

Comment: "I am using geom_linerange instead of geom_errorbar to get a vertical line in the legend" `geom_errorbar` gives a horizontal line, instead of a vertical one, which I don't think is as aesthetically pleasing in this use case.

Comment: for the example with `stat_summary` , I do not get the same plot as the one you have shown here - did you miss to include any additional code here ?

Comment: What difference(s) did you get?

Comment: I do get every thing except the legend.

Comment: That is odd -- I just pasted the code back in on my system, and it generates fine. Do you have some sort of `theme` setting that may be causing the issue? e.g., setting `legend.position = "none"` globally?