# Legend ggplot figure doesn't show for means, errorbars and coloured rectangle

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have been making this scatterplot of means in R and I know I should include all variables of interest as an aesthetic in the figure plot. However, in the figure that I created (see below), the  legend doesn't show.

The variables that I'm interested in are the means, errorbars and the coloured rectangles. Anyone knows how to plot them in a smart or manual manner?

```
df <- data.frame(weeks = c(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
             mean = c(64, 65, 66, 66, 66, 67),
             lowerCI = c(63.4, 64.9, 64.5, 63.8, 62.1, 66.8),
             upperCI = c(65.6, 65.1, 66.5, 67.2, 68.9, 67.2))

sp_ts <- ggplot(data = df,
            aes(x = weeks,
                y = mean))

sp_ts +
  geom_point(shape = 15,
         size = 4) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lowerCI,
                ymax = upperCI),
            width = 0.05,
            size = 0.5) +
  labs(title = "Scatterplot of means",
   x = "Weeks",
   y = "Means") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1, 4),
                 breaks = c(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(62, 69),
                 breaks = c(61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69)) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = -Inf, xmax = 2, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "light blue", alpha = 0.2) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 2, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Comment: You don't have a legend because you haven't specified anything above to put in a legend.  What is this legend supposed to differentiate?

Comment: I want the legend to inform the reader that the squares are means, the errorbars are 95% confidence intervals and the coloured rectangles are different groups. I suppose I could also do this in a comment below the graph, but I fancy it better to include it as a legend

Comment: That's not the typical purpose of a legend.  Usually, that information would belong in a caption above or below the graph.  A legend specifically maps features of the graph (line type, color, fill, point type) with subsets of the data (company A vs company B; treatment A vs treatment B), etc.

Comment: I am aware of the way in which these graphs are used in the scientific literature, but for communication purposes I prefer to have as much information in the graph as possible. My readers aren't usually fan of large pieces of text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way to show the legend (taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40383008/786542))

```r
library(ggplot2)

sp_ts1 <- sp_ts +
  geom_point(shape = 15, size = 4) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lowerCI, ymax = upperCI),
            width = 0.05,
            size = 0.5) +
  labs(title = "Scatterplot of means",
   x = "Weeks",
   y = "Means") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1, 4),
                 breaks = c(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(62, 69),
                 breaks = c(61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69)) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = -Inf, xmax = 2, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, 
           fill = "light blue", alpha = 0.2) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 2, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, 
           fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

sp_ts2 <- sp_ts1 +
  geom_point(aes(color = "Mean"), shape = 15, size = 4) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lowerCI, ymax = upperCI,
                      color = "95% CI"),
            width = 0.05,
            size = 0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("#666666", "#1B9E77")) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c("solid", "blank"), 
                                                   shape = c(NA, 15))))
sp_ts2
```

[image]

To show 95% CI as a vertical line, use `geom_linerange`:

```r
sp_ts3 <- sp_ts1 +
  geom_point(aes(color = "Mean"), shape = 15, size = 4) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = lowerCI, ymax = upperCI, 
                       color = "95% CI")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("#666666", "#1B9E77")) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c("solid", "blank"), 
                                                   shape = c(NA, 15))))
sp_ts3
```

[image]

**Edit:** To show the filled rectangles, we need to use `geom_rect` instead of `annotate`

```r
sp_ts3 + 
    geom_rect(aes(fill = "First"), xmin = -Inf, xmax = 2, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, 
           alpha = 0.1) +
    geom_rect(aes(fill = "Second"), xmin = 2, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, 
           alpha = 0.1) +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Group", 
                      values = c(`First` = "bisque", `Second` = "cornflowerblue")) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes= list(alpha = 0.6)))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you Tung, this will do for the means and errorbars. Do you also know how to incoorporate the rectangles?

Comment: I am sorry, just one more question. The squares of the means are now also colored, because the rectangles are placed on top. Do you know how I can configure the graph so that the mean squares are still black (or green in your case) and on top of the rectangles? So they have a solid color?

Comment: Alright, never mind, I found the solution: Just give the code that you want plotted on top below the code that you want to plot on the bottom. So: geom_rect preceeds geom_point